# MySQL database replication fails for some tables while using RubyRep

Tags: mysql, ruby, replication, database-replication

I'm setting up partial replication to my MySQL database using [RubyRep](https://www.rubyrep.org/). But it is not working for some tables. What did I do wrong?

This is a Linux CentOS server, running MySQL 5. I tried replicating two MySQL databases in local for two same kind of tables in two different databases, which is working perfectly. So I tried the same in the server. In the server when I try for the tables which I created newly, it works perfectly, but for some existing tables, it is not working.

The attendance table properties are

```
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ATTENDANCE_DATE   | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| STUDENT_ID        | int(10)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| CLASS_ID          | int(10)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| STAFF_ID          | int(10)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| ATTENDANCE_STATUS | char(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| LATE_STATUS       | char(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| LATE_TIME         | varchar(7)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| DROP_TIME         | time         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| PICK_TIME         | time         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| REMARKS           | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| SCHOOL_ID         | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| CREATED_ON        | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| CREATED_BY        | varchar(15)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| MODIFIED_ON       | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| MODIFIED_BY       | varchar(15)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

And the RubyRep config file is:

```
RR::Initializer::run do |config|                                                   
  config.left = {                                                                  
    :adapter  => 'mysql2',                                                         
    :database => 'database-A',                                          
    :username => '*******',                                                      
    :password => '*******',                                                   
    :host     => 'localhost'                                                       
  }                                                                                

  config.right = {                                                                 
    :adapter  => 'mysql2',                                                         
    :database => 'database-B',                                             
    :username => '*******',                                                      
    :password => '*******',                                                   
    :host     => 'localhost'                                                       
  }                                                                                

  config.left[:logger] = "log/left_database.log"                                   
  config.right[:logger] = "log/right_database.log"                                 
  config.options[:auto_key_limit] = 2                                              

  config.include_tables 'attendance', :replication_conflict_handing => :
left_wins, :sync_conflict_handling => :left_wins                                   
  # config.include_tables /^e/ # regexp matching all tables starting with e        
  # config.include_tables /./ # regexp matching all tables in the database         
end
```

I expect that when data is added in the attendance table in database-A, it should be replicated in the attendance table in the database-B.

Now while running the replicate command itself the command is failed with error message

`Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '), null, 'I');`

Comment: what is your source/destination mysql versions (full version please)?

Comment: This seems like a bug in rubyrep, since it's generating the SQL for you.

Comment: @danblack It looks like he's just replacating between databases on the same server,  so there can't be a version difference.

Comment: Doh - of course. Looks like no activity on https://github.com/rubyrep/rubyrep/ since Sept 2017. You might be on your own fixing it.

Comment: @danblack `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.26, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

Comment: @Barmar Yes you are correct, I'm replicating in the same server. Also do you know which one is better, replicating in the same server or putting the databases in a different server?

Comment: Usually the purpose of replication is for failover, so if one server goes down you can use the other, or load balancing to get more performance. I don't see the point of replicating within the same server.

Comment: Actually, we are planning to make a reporting database, since some queries are taking around 10seconds. We are planning to derive the data and keep the data ready in another table and use proper indexing and make the query faster. @Barmar

Comment: Derived tables are not the same thing as replication.

Comment: @Barmar We are thinking of writing triggers in the replicated DB, and insert processed data into the derived tables. I hope that is the best way to do this.